# Footer being cut off on bottom of page

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
#header {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
} 
#content {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: #898989;
}
```

I'm using a really common method to keep the footer at the bottom of the page, and it only half works. I learnt about it through a blog, and it was really helpful at first, however at some point editing my website it became broken. It displays a very small portion of the footer div, and while the rest is there, you have to scroll down to see it.

Without scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxI2s.png

With scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umsZ3.png

I don't know what I'm missing here, it just isn't working.

EDIT: So I know this was a terrible question, I left out a lot of stuff because it's a company website and I was just worried about what I included. The culprit turned out to be the margins on the #header element. Removing those made everything work like a charm.

Comment: Try creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it so we can see the actual broken version.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML code I think that the problem here is that the items inside the footer are taller than your predefined 80px.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this was a terrible question, I left out a lot of stuff because it's a company website and I was just worried about what I included. The culprit turned out to be the margins on the #header element. Removing those made everything work like a charm.

Comment: But you could always keep your original question and use positioning to place the border too

Answer (score -1):

I have changed only the bottom part

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
#header {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
} 
#content {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: #898989;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
.
</div>
<div id="content">
.
</div>
<div id="footer">
.
</div>
```

does that help?